# How to run XCTest UI without using code on iOS device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xctest

Is there a way to deploy an iOS ipa or AppNameUITests-Runner on the device and run the test cases?

We were able to successfully deploy the AppNameUITests-Runner using command line.
But, it does not launch the tests.